# convert python script and its dependent scripts to exe

Tags: python

I have these python scripts which are dependent on each other --

`py_scripts\format py_scripts\plugins py_scripts\utils py_scripts_main_.py py_scripts_pycache_ py_scripts\format\bit.py py_scripts\format\cmd.py py_scripts\format\ctr.py py_scripts\format\fnt.py py_scripts\format\hmp.py py_scripts\format\lmp.py py_scripts\format\mef.py py_scripts\format\qvm py_scripts\format\tex.py py_scripts\format\tga.py py_scripts\format\thm.py py_scripts\format\tlm.py py_scripts\format\tmm.py py_scripts\format\wav.py py_scripts\format_pycache_ py_scripts\format\qvm\op5.py py_scripts\format\qvm\op7.py py_scripts\format\qvm\ops.py py_scripts\format\qvm_init_.py py_scripts\format\qvm_pycache_ py_scripts\format\qvm_pycache_\op5.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format\qvm_pycache_\op7.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format\qvm_pycache_\ops.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format\qvm_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\bit.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\cmd.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\ctr.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\fnt.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\hmp.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\lmp.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\mef.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\tex.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\tga.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\thm.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\tlm.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\tmm.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\format_pycache_\wav.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\bit py_scripts\plugins\cmd py_scripts\plugins\filesys py_scripts\plugins\fnt py_scripts\plugins\hmp py_scripts\plugins\ilff py_scripts\plugins\level py_scripts\plugins\lmp py_scripts\plugins\mef py_scripts\plugins\qvm py_scripts\plugins\tex py_scripts\plugins\thm py_scripts\plugins\tlm py_scripts\plugins\tmm py_scripts\plugins\wav py_scripts\plugins\bit\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\bit_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\bit_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\bit_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\bit_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\cmd\check.py py_scripts\plugins\cmd_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\cmd_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\cmd_pycache_\check.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\cmd_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\filesys\compfiles.py py_scripts\plugins\filesys\copyfiles.py py_scripts\plugins\filesys\countexts.py py_scripts\plugins\filesys\listfiles.py py_scripts\plugins\filesys\treefiles.py py_scripts\plugins\filesys_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\filesys_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\filesys_pycache_\compfiles.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\filesys_pycache_\copyfiles.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\filesys_pycache_\countexts.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\filesys_pycache_\listfiles.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\filesys_pycache_\treefiles.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\filesys_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\fnt\check.py py_scripts\plugins\fnt_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\fnt_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\fnt_pycache_\check.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\fnt_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\hmp\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\hmp_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\hmp_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\hmp_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\hmp_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\ilff\chunkset.py py_scripts\plugins\ilff\chunksizegcd.py py_scripts\plugins\ilff\chunksizeset.py py_scripts\plugins\ilff_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\ilff_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\ilff_pycache_\chunkset.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\ilff_pycache_\chunksizegcd.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\ilff_pycache_\chunksizeset.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\ilff_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\level\terrain.py py_scripts\plugins\level_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\level_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\level_pycache_\terrain.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\level_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\lmp\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\lmp_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\lmp_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\lmp_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\lmp_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\mef\check.py py_scripts\plugins\mef_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\mef_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\mef_pycache_\check.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\mef_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm\ast.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\decompile.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\obj.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\objects.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\qsc.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\terrain.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_\ast.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_\decompile.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_\obj.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_\objects.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_\qsc.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache_\terrain.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\qvm_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\tex\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\tex_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\tex_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\tex_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\tex_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\thm\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\thm_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\thm_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\thm_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\thm_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\tlm\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\tlm_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\tlm_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\tlm_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\tlm_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\tmm\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\tmm_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\tmm_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\tmm_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\tmm_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\wav\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\wav_init_.py py_scripts\plugins\wav_pycache_ py_scripts\plugins\wav_pycache_\convert.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\plugins\wav_pycache__init_.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\utils\fs.py py_scripts\utils\ilff.py py_scripts\utils_pycache_ py_scripts\utils_pycache_\fs.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts\utils_pycache_\ilff.cpython-36.pyc py_scripts_pycache__main_.cpython-36.pyc`

I want to compile all these to a single exe file that works well with parameters...

Can anyone please help me ?
Thanks

My research :
i downloaded 'pyinstaller' from command line using 'pip' , then i used 'cd' command to locate my scripts folder , then i used 'pyinstaller --onefile **main**.py' command from command line and then it converted it to .exe

But the exe located in now 'dist' directory is showing an error on running [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs0fl.png)

[error output at command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OryU6.png)

About my python scripts :
my scripts are actually dependent on 2 more external libraries "numpy, pillow, lxml", the '**main**.py' used other scripts to work well. Also i wanted to pack all the file ".py, .pyc etc..." to exe. My script works well with parameters and is responsible for converting files. I don't wanted others to use my script it contains very sensitive data.

After all these info can anyone please help me ?
Thanks again

Comment: yes, i tried using pyinstaller and p2exe, but when i opens my exe file it shows some error

Comment: I can't find this information in your question.

Comment: No, the information you provide is not enough. Do you need to pack all those pyc-files or just the py-files? If yes, why? Are there external libraries involved or are the scripts self-contained, using only the standard library? What is the error message (+traceback, if given) you get? What exact commands have you tried to create the exe files? Which python version are you using? Which version of pyinstaller and py2exe are you using? If there are external libraries, which versions of those are you using? You cannot just say "I have a problem" and expect people to help you for free.

Comment: Ok, 
Yes i want to pack all files and folder
External libraries are also involved in it
There is just an invalid exe error
I followed the tutorial here https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/
there are external libraries used in it and all should be of the latest version released

I though you all would understand me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyinstaller for creating a single exe file which would be executable.
https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

I think this would be helpful.

Comment: I tried it an it shows an error at the image in question